# wpf MediaElement memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I am using a media element to display several kinds of resources (image, gif, video)

The issue is that the media element will consume more memory each time I assign it a new source.
The garbage collector is not collecting anything there. I have found several questions about the same topic in forums and on stack overflow but none of them received a proper answer.

So this my wpf code:

```
private void LoadInformation(FileInfo file)
{
    imageDisplay.Source = new Uri(file.FullName);
}

<MediaElement x:Name="imageDisplay" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" UnloadedBehavior="Close" LoadedBehavior="Manual"
            MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded" ></MediaElement>
```

this is my code to update in .xaml.xs:

```
// When the media opens, initialize the "Seek To" slider maximum value
// to the total number of miliseconds in the length of the media clip.
private void Element_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageDisplay.Play();
}

// When the media playback is finished. Stop() the media to seek to media start.
private void Element_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageDisplay.Stop();
    imageDisplay.Source = null;
}
```

This is according to official microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-mediaelement-play-pause-stop-volume-and-speed?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

if I execute `LoadInformation` in a loop, my memory goes up happily, until the application crashes.

If I stop the loop before the app crashes and let it run for a while, gc will not free up the memory
[image]

### Update 1

Managing the MediaElement Manually does not make any difference:
LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

```
imageDisplay.Stop();
imageDisplay.Close();
imageDisplay.Source = null;
imageDisplay.Source = new Uri(file.FullName);
imageDisplay.Play();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling `imageDisplay.Close()` in your `Element_MediaEnded` method? I know `UnloadedBehavior="Close"` should do it automatically but it might force it to release the memory

Comment: yes I did. this requires LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of searching and not finding ANY working solution, I found some hints at least.

### Issue:

Take the following information with a huge grain of salt.

What I think happened is that MediaElement is a Legacy component from Winforms wrapped in WPF. I have seen several hints such as the change of source from stream to uri.
What caught my attention was that some methods such as `mediaelement.Finalize()` were removed.
My best guess is that MediaElement simply should not be used nowadays anymore?

### Solution

As seen in my screenshot above, a memory consumption of 64gb for displaying a 84kb jpg is indiscutable. I have searched around for alternatives.
What proofed sufficient for me was the WebView2 control.

Usage:

```
<wpf:WebView2 x:Name="ImageWebView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></wpf:WebView2>
```

```
ImageWebView.Source = new Uri(CollectionInformation.Information.NftPreviewFiles[key].FullName);
```

now no memory impact whatsoever could be found:
[image]

unfortunately, WebView2 is a nuget package, albeit from microsoft.
it can be found by the name `Microsoft.Web.WebView2`

I hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this code from your program:

```
imageDisplay.Close();
```

I don't use this and I don't have a memory leak.

To stop or play a video I use:

```
MElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
MElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop;
```

Good luck...